# using variables in rails erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm coming from a .net c# razor background, so I'm wondering how I might do the following in rails .erb view.

Razor:

```
@{var i = 0}
<table>
     <tr><th>name</th></tr>
     @foreach item in collection{
        <tr>
             <td>@i++.@item.name</td>
        </tr>
     }
</table>
```

I want a way to use an iteration variable in the view.  Does a rails erb file have the ability to do this?  where I can create the variable in the view and interact with it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though this has a negative effort number, this question/answer really has helped me.  I hope it helps others in the future :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs pretty much answer this: https://apidock.com/ruby/ERB

Although I wouldn't do it like that, rather:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>name</th></tr>

  <% collection.each_with_index do |item, i| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= i %>. <%= item %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

To answer your *specific* but non-canonical-Ruby question, sure:

```
<% i = 0 %>
<table>
  <% collection.each do |item| %>
    <!-- Etc -->
    <%= i += 1 %>
```

(Not clear to me if you want zero- or one-based indexing; adjust all examples as required.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.    The .item was a typo, the item is the object i want to print out.  and the period (.) is just for the number showing what row is on, kind of like an ordered list <ol>